# Syntax error or access violation: 1064

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have a problem in my SQL it looks like. I have tried looking around through docs and can't seem to find my error.

Heres the error:

[11-Jun-2014 17:56:46] WARNING: [pool www] child 12509 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END WHERE id IN ()' at line 1' in /var/www/html/output.php:53"

I should add that the code works AS IS... it's only when I try to add the following `$options` that the errors appear:

```
  $options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
  );
```

and the code:

```
  # Also prepare SQL for update below
  $sql = "UPDATE `headlines` SET views = CASE id ";
  foreach ($headlines as $headline) {
    $id = $headline['id'];
    $sql .= sprintf("WHEN %d THEN views + 1 ", $id);
  } 
  # Update views
  $placeholders = rtrim(str_repeat('?, ', count($ids)), ', ');
  $sql .= "END WHERE id IN ($placeholders)";
  $q = $db->prepare($sql);
  $q->execute($ids);
```

Generated query:

```
UPDATE `headlines` SET views = CASE id WHEN 1364 THEN views + 1 WHEN 1365 THEN views + 1 WHEN 1366 THEN views + 1 END WHERE id IN (?, ?, ?)
```

Its also possible it could be empty, like such:

```
UPDATE `headlines` SET views = CASE id END WHERE id IN ()
```

Comment: show us the generated query.

Comment: Try it like this `CASE WHEN id=1364 THEN views + 1 WHEN id=1365...`

Comment: didnt seem to work. I thought it did for a moment, but no dice.

Comment: Weird.Try adding an ELSE condition.

Comment: Why not simply use `UPDATE headlines SET views = views + 1 WHERE id IN (1364,1365,1366)`? All of that extra logic looks unnecessary.

Comment: Youre right @Sammitch... thanks, that makes things way easier. Although, now the error changed to this: `[11-Jun-2014 18:56:20] WARNING: [pool www] child 12896 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1' in file.php:51"`

Comment: I forgot to mention... my code works fine as is. its only when I try to add the following lines that everything breaks: `$options = array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking PDO to send an exception when an error is encountered and you are doing nothing to catch that exception.  That is the reason for the fatal error, and why you seem to see different behavior when changing PDO configuration (you just might not have been noticing the error before if you weren't logging it or looking in your logs).

Now the reason for the SQL error is given in the exception message.  Your problem starts with the usage of `END` in your query.  `CASE id END` is not valid syntax.

It is unclear to me in the generated SQL why you are using a case statement at all. As suggested above in comments, the WHERE clause you have specified would only execute the update on the specific id's provided, so the CASE statement is superfluous, not too mention it goes against the approach of parametrizing your input.

This should be all you need:

```
UPDATE headlines SET views = views + 1 WHERE id IN (?,?,?)
```

Comment: What if i include a `require('db.php');` at the top of all my files for the initial `$db = new PDO()`. I think the way I catch errors is to do this is to use `try{ x } catch { y }` right? Is it possible i can put the `require` statement in place of the `x` above? Or can I wrap only this one line `$q->execute($ids);` in a try?

Comment: @Tallboy Good coding practice would have you wrapping any code which could possibly throw exceptions in a try-catch.  At a minimum in your case, you should wrap the prepare and execute steps (and also likely steps where you work with the result set) within a try catch block.

Comment: Are you available if I ask you 1 or 2 questions about PDO, not on stack overflow? Maybe email? I'd pay for your time.

Comment: @Tallboy Thanks for the offer, but I am not really accepting any freelance work or anything like that.  PDO is pretty well documented and has tons of usage examples on SO and the internet as a whole.  I would encourage to try to research the areas you have questions, and, if you run into implementation problems, feel free to ask questions on SO.